# What is linuxexchange.org?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was searching for some linux stuff today, and I came over [linuxexchange.org](http://linuxexchange.org/).

It seems very much like it is trying to imitate a StackExchange site, but I couldn't find anything at all on the page that said it were related to SA in any way.

Are they trying to copy/fake the StackExchange concept? Is that even allowed? And do anybody here even know about it (I couldn't find a single question here at meta when searching for linuxexchange...)?

Comment: On a related subject, there is an SE2 Linux site: [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to be a StackExchange 1.0 Site.

```
 <meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

Comment: @Henrik P. Hessel: and what does that mean? If you for instance look at the "administrator" (http://linuxexchange.org/users/2/jeremy), he describes himself as the "Founder of LinuxExchange". I didn't thing StackExchange sites had founders...?

Comment: Don't know if there's any information on SE 1.0 here on meta but there's a wikipedia entry on this topic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network#StackExchange_1.0

Comment: @Nailuj: Prior to SE 2.0, anybody could start their own Stack Exchange site.  So yes, they had founders.  In a sense, SE 2.0 sites have founders too; they're the ones who participate in the Area 51 definition and private beta phases.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Stack Exchange wasn't free previously.

Comment: Thanks all, that cleared things up a bit :-) I wasn't aware of the licenceable SE 1.0 model. I still find it a bit strange though, that I couldn't find a single reference to SE anywhere on the sit, such as the faq (other than the tiny note in the page source pointed out by Henrik P. Hessel).

Comment: If the SE 1.0 license allows for it, it does not have to be strange - it is similar to how blogs do not necessarily mention which blog engine they run on.